# How do you make certain category options non-selectable (but still there/reportable)?

Tags: drupal, database

Is there an extension available that allows you to make certain category options (on a 'pick list') non-selectable, but are still there/reportable?  And can you do this based upon a previous field selection?  E.g. The 'pick list' for a field called 'Group Name' doesn't allow an 'old' choice to be selected, but it is still there on other records and is reportable.  And could the availability of the pick list be dependent upon a previous choice, e.g. an 'Area' field calculated using address?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't a scenario covered by core or an extension. Only custom fields can be set readonly. For a fast but hacky solution you could try a javascript approach.

Comment: nielo's answer is right.  It is a much-debated topic: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8719/can-i-report-data-from-a-disabled-custom-field-or-option and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/19.  The summary is that different people have different opinions on what "disabled" should mean.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the second part of your question - yes, there is my [Field Lookup](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/fieldlookup/tree/master) extension which allows you to "chain select" - much like picking a country will limit the choice of available states, you can make one select list dependent on another.

However, it's still in an early (i.e. unfinished) state; I actually have some funding to flesh it out a bit more, but it's not the priority of the client at the moment.  If you open a new question around its use, I can document it enough for you to get it working (if it meets your needs without modification; it likely does).